# Help me out on memory leaks issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, memory-leaks

Pls look at the below code. when i run my application using Run with performance tool for checking the leaks...that shows that leaks in this code....

Please help me to solve any leaks in this below code.

thanks for any help...

```
NSString* imgName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:
                                                  @"QW%d",frontCardImgNo] ;

myGridView.imgView.image  = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:
[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: imgName ofType:@"jpg"]];

[imgName release];

[myGridView.pView addSubview:myGridView.imgView];
```

Comment: There are definitely no leaks here. Instruments may show false positives and is not always precise with regard to where the leak has occurred. Try "Build and Analyze", maybe the Analyzer will catch something.

Comment: there's no memory leaking on that code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing in that code is leaking. What may be triggering Instruments is either `myGridView`, `myGridView.pView` or `myGridView.imgView` leaking. If one of these views leaks, anything contained within those view hierarchies will also leak. Are you properly releasing your ivars/properties in `dealloc` within both `myGridView` and whatever owns `myGridView` (presumably a View Controller)?